# CSS menu make links centre

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this css for my horizontal menu:

```
nav {  
    height: 40px;  
    width: 100%;  
    background: #F00;  
    font-size: 11pt;  
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;  
    position: relative;  
    border-bottom: 2px solid #FFFFFF;  
}  
nav ul {  
    padding: 0;  
    margin: 0 auto;  
    width: 600px;  
    height: 40px;  
}
nav li {  
    display: inline;  
    float: left;  
}  
.clearfix:before,  
.clearfix:after {  
    content: " ";  
    display: table;  
}  
.clearfix:after {  
    clear: both;  
}  
.clearfix {  
    *zoom: 1;  
}  
nav a {  
    color: #000000;  
    display: inline-block;  
    width: 100px;  
    text-align: center;  
    text-decoration: none;  
    line-height: 40px;  
}  
nav li a {  
    border-right: 1px solid #FFFFFF;  
    box-sizing:border-box;  
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;  
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;  
}  
nav li:last-child a {  
    border-right: 0;  
}  
nav a:hover, nav a:active {  
    background-color: #000000;
    color:#FFFFFF;  
} 
nav a#pull {  
    display: none;  
}  
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {  
    nav {   
        height: auto;  
    }  
    nav ul {  
        width: 100%;  
        display: block;  
        height: auto;  
    }  
    nav li {  
        width: 50%;  
        float: left;  
        position: relative;  
    }  
    nav li a {  
        border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;  
        border-right: 1px solid #FFFFFF;  
    }  
    nav a {  
        text-align: left;  
        width: 100%;  
        text-indent: 25px;  
    }  
}  
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {  
    nav {  
        border-bottom: 0;  
    }  
    nav ul {  
        display: none;  
        height: auto;  
    }  
    nav a#pull {  
        display: block;  
        background-color: #FF0;  
        width: 100%;  
        position: relative;  
    }  
    nav a#pull:after {  
        content:"";  
        background: url('nav-icon.png') no-repeat;  
        width: 30px;  
        height: 30px;  
        display: inline-block;  
        position: absolute;  
        rightright: 15px;  
        top: 10px;  
    }  
}  
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {  
    nav li {  
        display: block;  
        float: none;  
        width: 100%;  
    }  
    nav li a {  
        border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;  
    }  
}
```

how can i make the li links display in the centre?

here is a fiddle of the menu: http://jsfiddle.net/zJq52/

Answer (score 2):

I would do this:

```
nav ul {  
    padding: 0;  
    margin: 0 auto;  
    width: 600px;  
    height: 40px;  
    text-align: center; // add text-align
}
nav li {  
    display: inline; // no more float in here 
}
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/zJq52/2/)

**Update 1:**
To make the width auto:

```
nav a {  
    color: #000000;  
    display: inline-block;  
    width: auto;  // changed this from width: 100px; to auto. 
    text-align: center;  
    text-decoration: none;  
    line-height: 40px;  
}
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/BMepK/3/)

**Update 2:** 
Finished Version!

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/zJq52/13/)

Comment: Works great - http://jsfiddle.net/zJq52/3/ - is it possible to make each li link auto width rather than being a fixed width?

Comment: Yes, change the width in `nav a` from `width: 100px;` to `width: auto;` I will put a demo in my answer.

Comment: excellent - i have added padding: 5px; onto nav a also but its not looking too great... how can i add padding to the right and left?

Comment: You didnt put the first bit I said about. this is the one you just gave me updated to center.  [http://jsfiddle.net/zJq52/9/](http://jsfiddle.net/zJq52/9/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zJq52/10/ - if you hover over services there is a small margin to the left but i want to get rid of that but i still want a margin/padding on the left/right of each link so they arent so close together. however the hover colour (black) needs to reach the white borders

Comment: They are spaces that are in the html. Make sure you get rid of all of the spaces that are around the `<li></li>` tags e.g: if I move all of the <li> together the spaces disappear. (not sure why I cant next line them. [DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/zJq52/12/)

Comment: Last comment then please select a answer as they are many. In my edit I will link you to the finished version. With everything you have asked for. including padding.

Answer (score 1):

## [Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BMepK/)

Change `nav a` to this:

```
nav a {
   text-align: center;
   width: 100%;
}
```

I also have to mention that you have two `nav a`s. You should merge them into one and apply a little change:

```
nav a {  
    color: #000000;  
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;  
    text-decoration: none;  
    line-height: 40px;  
    width: 100%;  
    padding: 0 10px; 
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5DRkP/) for the merged one and the result for me:

[image: Result]

If you want to center the buttons as a row in the horizontal bar then just simply apply a `width` to the `<ul>` so add a new class: `<ul class="clearfix cont">` and style it in a media rule so it won't affect the other layouts:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {  
   .cont {width: 380px;}
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G2fWj/) and the result:

[image: Final result]

Comment: Even in your demo the links are not centred.

Comment: That's not what they asked for, when the nav is on one line they wanted the links to sit in the center of the nav.

Comment: Im using Chrome and this is how it looks: [Link here](http://oi43.tinypic.com/so26hk.jpg)

Comment: @Ruddy Ok I interpreted differently, but now I implemented your interpretation as well

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you mean, but if you mean centering all the li in  relation to its parent change the width from 600px to 400px

```
nav ul {
padding: 0;
width: 400px;
height: 40px;
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
}
```

demo: - http://jsfiddle.net/zQehH/2/

Answer (score 0):

[**UPDATED DEMO** <kbd>JSFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/zJq52/5/)

Here is the correct way to do the stuff you want

**CSS-**

```
nav ul {  
    padding: 0;  
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:800px;
    text-align:center;
    height: 40px;  
}
nav li {  
    display: inline-block;  //use inline block
}  
nav a {  
    color: #000000;  
    display: inline-block;  
    padding: 0 20px; //use padding instead of width
    text-decoration: none;  
    line-height: 40px;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Making the choice for a float isn't always the right one.

Your example contains a fixed width of 600px on the "nav ul" element is weird when you only have 4 elements of ~100px width. You can't center that...

I basically removed the float, and the clearfixes.
And then I've made it to contain the following based on how I'd do it..

```
nav {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
nav ul {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: auto;
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline;
  display: inline-block;
}
nav ul li a {
  /*width: 100px;*/
  width: auto;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

My example:
http://jsfiddle.net/xewl/4CrdN/1/

I see that you have other versions that do kinda work as planned:
http://jsfiddle.net/zJq52/6/
You didn't set a width on "nav ul li a" here.
But why is there a width on "nav ul" of 400px?

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
nav li a {  
border-right: 1px solid #FFFFFF;  
box-sizing:border-box;  
-moz-box-sizing:border-box;  
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;  

text-align:center; /*Added Line*/
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Super simple.

Add `text-align: center` to `nav ul` and remove `float: left` from `nav li`.

```
nav ul {  
    padding: 0;  
    margin: 0 auto;  
    width: 600px;  
    height: 40px;  
    text-align: center;
}
nav li {  
    display: inline;   
}
```

Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qwUF7/